# Find Lipschitz constant for non differentiable function $f(t,y) = t y sin(|\alpha y|)$ $t\in[0, 1], y\in[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Find a Lipschitz constant (in the y variable) for the following function on the given domain.

$f(t,y) = t y sin(|\alpha y|)$, $t\in[0, 1], y\in[-\pi,\pi]$,
$\alpha>0$ is a parameter and your Lipschitz constant should depend on $\alpha$. Your Lipschitz constant must be valid for all $\alpha$ but it does not need to be the smallest possible.

I know that a function can have lipschitz constant with out being differentiable.
Clearly this one is non differentiable at $y=0$. But i normally have only worked with either differenetiable functions or easier than this one. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the downvote is that such an ovious questions and would it hurt to give atleast a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was extra info given as follows

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on an interval $I$ it means that there is a constant $L$, such that
$|f(u)-f(v)| \le L|u-v|$, $u,v \in I$

with the following properties:

1) If a function is continuously differentiable and the derivative satisfies $|f'| \le K$ on interval $I$, then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $I$ and $K$ can be taken to be a Lipschitz constant for $f$ on interval $I$.

2) If $f(y)$ has Lipschitz constant $L$, then $|f(y)|$ is also Lipschitz continuous on I with Lipschitz constant $L$.

3) If $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ are Lipschitz continuous on a closed interval $I$ with Lipschitz constants $L_1 , L_2$ respectively,
then $f(y)+g(y)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $I$ with Lipschitz constant $L_1+L_2$

4) If $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ are Lipschitz continuous on a closed interval $I$ with Lipschitz constants $L_1 , L_2$ respectively,and the absolute value of each of $f$ and $g$ has a maximum $M_1,M_2$ on $I$ respectively. Then $f(y) g(y)$ is Lipschitz continuous on I with Lipschitz constant is $M_1L_2+M_2L_1$

5) If $f:I_1 \mapsto I_2$ and $g:I_2 \mapsto I_3$ are Lipschitz continuous on a closed interval $I_1,I_2,I_3$ with Lipschitz constants $L_1 , L_2$ respectively, then the composite functions $g(f(y))$ is Lipschitz continuous on $I_1$ with Lipschitz constant $L=L_1L_2$

You can't use 1 as your function is non-differentiable.

However, consider first rule 5:

let $f=|\alpha y|$ then it's $L_1= \alpha$

let $g=sin(x)$ this is differentiable using rule 1 $L_2=1$ now using rule 5   $$g(f(y))=sin|\alpha y|$$ and its Lipschitz constant is $L=L_1L_2=\alpha$

Now, use rule 4:

let $f=ty$ then max $M_1=\pi$, and $L_1=1$

let $g=sin|\alpha y|$ as we already got $L_2= \alpha$  clearly $M_2=1$

Using rule 4, $$L=M_1L_2+M_2L_1=1+\pi \alpha$$

That's the final answer